# What can be a proper translation for: "degree obtained with Merit"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

In Great Britain you can get a degree with Merit or Distinction from any university when you have high grades. What is the equivalent or translation for this in German?

Comment: "Diplom mit Auszeichnung" might be close, is, however not as "standardized" as it is in the UK and varies between Universities. Heck, I don't even know if they still use it.

Answer (score 3):

I have a degree "with merit". For my German CVs, I do not translate the "with merit" because there is no proper equivalent. I think it is better to add some kind of explanation that "with merit" is some kind of "Auszeichnung", maybe adding the list of possible degrees from the university (e.g. for my degree, there is "pass", "with merit" and "with distinction").

This is of course part of a more general problem: there is not proper comparison between English marks or degrees and the German grading system.